# How to get string input from user and output total character value of of string entered?

Tags: java, string, character

How to get string input from user and output total character value of of string entered?

I know that string length is different than character value. Just need total character value of the string input by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use java.util.Scanner class to read a string like this

```
java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.next();  
int n = s.length();
```

you can insert a string without white spaces and n is the length of the string before the first white space